# Python 3 printing \n instead of just a new line in web scraper

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So im working on a webscraper for youtube playlists, but I think i've ran into a bug or just something I'm having a really difficult time understanding.

```
import os
import io
import pandas as pd
from numpy import arange
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

# ----
print("Paste the Youtube playlist's page(URL) here.")
url = input()

uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.find("div", {"id": "content"})

# - Video Count
a = containers.findAll("td", {"class": "pl-video-title"})
b =(len(a))
total =(b)
d = 0

# Finds titles
for i in range(total):
    titles = containers.findAll("td", {"class": "pl-video-title"})
    titles_int = (int(d),(titles[d].text))
    print (titles_int)
    d += 1

# Finds links
links = containers.findAll("a")
for link in links:
    print(link.get("href"), link.text[0])
```

It used to print actual new lines vs the \n, but now despite there being no encoding attributes, it still does it. I do not understand why it's doing this as there's no encoding attributes really. All I can really figure out is that it's being prompted by this line `titles_int = (int(d),(titles[d].text))`.

Link used: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOzDu-MXXLliO9fBNZOQTBDddoA3FzZUo
Current output:

```
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:04:45) [MSC v.1900 32 bit 
(Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
=== RESTART: C:\Users\Trillz\Desktop\Youtube to Phone\Playlist Scraper3.py ===
Paste the Youtube playlist's page(URL) here.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOzDu-MXXLliO9fBNZOQTBDddoA3FzZUo
(0, "\n\n      Kina - u're mine (ft. shiloh)\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n")
(1, '\n\n      Kina - get you the moon (ft. Snow)\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n')
(2, '\n\n      ＦＯＲ ＹＯＵ\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n')
(3, '\n\n      Kina - Nobody Cares (ft. Shiloh)\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n')
(4, '\n\n      beowulf - savior\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n')
(5, '\n\n      dybredly - you are always wrong (ft. Shiloh)\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n')
(6, "\n\n      Sarcastic Sounds - I Don't Sleep\n    \n\nby the bootleg boy\n\n\n\n")
```

Comment: @meowgoesthedog yes it is! My bad, typo, ill edit it in the main post

Comment: Can you show us exactly what kind of output you have? And what you would expect?

Comment: @vinzee Sure! Just edited in the current output. Using the first as an example, What I was aiming for was (using the first as an example):

0
         Kina - u're mine (ft. shiloh)
    the bootleg boy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your code like this:

```
# Finds titles
for i in range(total):
    titles = containers.findAll("td", {"class": "pl-video-title"})
    print(int(d), titles[d].text)
    d += 1
```

Otherwise, you create a `tuple` object and printing tuples leads to this kind of problem. You can see why in this answer: [print tuple beautifully with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586207/print-tuple-beautifully-with-newline)